# Strange output with array.map

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm building a simple react native mobile app and get data from AsyncStorage.  Here is a function that gets the data when the component mounts

```
  getClassData = async id => {
    const allRegs = (await AsyncStorage.getItem("regs")) || "[]";
    const items = JSON.parse(allRegs);
    console.log("All REGS", items);
    const classData = items.map((y, i) => (
    <View key={i}>
     <Text>{y.email}, {y.name}</Text>
      </View>
    ));
    console.log('ALL DATA',str)
  };
```

the first output is normal and looks like this.

```
All REGS
   Array [
     Object {
       "classID": 1,
        "email": "Mp@fgh.com",
        "name": "Allen",
          },
       ]
```

but after the map function that out in the console is this

ALL DATA

```
  Array [
   Object {
   "$$typeof": Symbol(react.element),
   "_owner": null,
   "key": "0",
   "props": Object {
     "children": Object {
    "$$typeof": Symbol(react.element),
    "_owner": null,
    "key": null,
    "props": Object {
    ......
```

Why isn't this simply giving me the output I expected (just a simple output with the data in views and text?  Thanks.

Comment: map works fine make sure to pass proper array, may be ur array item has jsx.

Answer (score 1):

AsyncStorage returns a promise. You need to call `.then()` to get the value when it is ready.

```
getClassData = async id => {
    await AsyncStorage.getItem("regs").then((allRegs) => {
        const items = JSON.parse(allRegs);
        console.log("All REGS", items);
        const classData = items.map((y, i) => {
            return(
                <View key={i}>
                    <Text>{y.email}{y.name}</Text>
                </View>
            );
        });
        console.log('ALL DATA', str);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const items = [
       {
       name:'aaaa',
       email:'aaaa@gmail.com'
        },
       {
       name:<View>aksjdha</View>,
       email:'bbbb@gmail.com'
        },
       <View>qwds</View>
     ]


    let classData = items.map((y, i) => (
    <View key={i}>
     <Text>{y.email}, {y.name}</Text>
      </View>
    ));
```

you have something like jsx in your array object check it once.

Comment: Thanks. I’ll check that